# Putting 2 pages of data into a single page for Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a page that shows a student's grades. I would like to insert another page after this page which shows the grade descriptions.

How would I go about doing that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add a group on the report be student ID / primary key
- Add your page of descriptions in the group footer.
- In your group footer settings, check the "New page before" option

Comment: The group footer would be the page footer?

Comment: No, the group footer would be the group footer after you add a grouping on the student.